# Space between li

Tags: css, html-lists

Why is there an space between li and how to remove it?
(Perhaps I could solve it with float or absolute positioning but I want the text adapt to the length of each word and the whole ul be centered)

Here is a place to play and check: http://jsfiddle.net/Z258Q/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second more long</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a { outline:0; text-decoration: none ; color:#aaa; }

ul {
    margin:40px auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border:1px solid; border-color:#ccc;
    border-bottom:0px; border-top:0px;
    height:8px; line-height:8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    display:block; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you made them `inline-block`. It means the browser will compound whitespace between the inline elements to a single space and uses it to render the items inline...

The solution can be simply to make sure no whitespace is left between the elements, like I did in [your update jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Z258Q/2/).

As for having only a single border, left and right, see comments and the [updated jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Z258Q/5).

Comment: Ok. I understand. Your answer is correct. I had the hope that if the 2 borders where in the same place I could see only one. But this is not the case. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @Nrc simple, I changed your border property, combined it into one single right border, then added a left border to the first li only. http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Z258Q/5/

Comment: Funnily enough, I had to solve a similar problem for work yesterday, that solution is visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/3ajj8/ which avoids the whole gap thing slightly more gracefull and has better degradation (in ie7).

Answer (score 6):

Because you've used `inline-block` as the display type, the white-space is taken into account in the output. Remove the white-space in your markup and the gap will go with it.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">First</a>
    </li><li> <!-- < The gap WAS between this closing and opening tag -->
        <a href="#">Second more long</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's your [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z258Q/1/)

Comment: Ok. I understand. Your answer is correct. I had the hope that if the 2 borders where in the same place I could see only one. But this is not the case. Do you know how to solve that?